# Two screen merging with each other - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So two screens are merging with each other even while using the exact attribute. Let's say screen 1 which is the home screen is merging with screen 2 which is not home screen. A possible solution to this might be using switch but I have like 10 routes, Can I use switch with like 10 routes? If yes then please mention it. Example of my code is like this

```
<Route path='/' exact component={HomeScreen} />
<Route path='/admin/products' exact component={AdminPanelProductChanger} />
```

Comment: You have to use `<Switch>`... I don't know why it would be limited only for two routes. As [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) says: _<Switch> is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every <Route> that matches the location renders inclusively._